# Is there a way to Programmatically distinguish between Person and Non Person Account fields

Tags: fields, person-accounts

Is there a Salesforce provided method/process to Programmatically distinguish between PersonAccount and Business Account fields ?

I am using the getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields to get fields of Account where result includes PersonAccount and Business type Account Fields as well.

Is this a right way to identify Person Account fields using the condition as in the code snippet below. Am I missing anything here?

```
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.Account.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (String f : fieldMap.keySet()){
      DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = fieldMap.get(f).getDescribe();
      if ((f.startsWith('person') && !fieldDescribe.isCustom()) || f.endsWith('__pc') || fieldDescribe.isNameField())
          System.debug( f );
}
```

[Similar Question (Old)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8486/getting-person-account-fields-using-apex)
There exist a very old post with same question, which does not have a solution. Hence I created this Question.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In the question you referenced, one of the answers mentions that Person account fields end in `__pc`, so you should be able to use `getName()` on the DescribeFieldResult and go from there.

Comment: @DavidCheng

Yes thats one missing part ( fields ending with __pc are just custom fields),  Custom fields added to Contact object are considered as Person Account Custom Fields which ends with __pc.  
And Standard fields starts with "person" with no suffix.  
Guess we covered all possible cases of Person account fields, Please correct  me if I am wrong. 

(1) >> Name fields (excluding 'Name') . . . .
(2) >> Standard Person Account Fields  (fieldName starts with "person" & is Not a Custom field) . . . .
(3) >> Custom Person Account Fields (fieldName ends with __pc)